# Exchange Web Service- FindItem error

Tags: exchangewebservices, server-error

We use EWS FindItem method to get mails' ID, and everything seems OK at the beginning.
However,we met ErrorInternalServerError error when we tried to make a paged request by using IndexedPageItemView in FindItem.
The xml created by gSOAP is as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope 
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/20    01/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
<SOAP-ENV:Header><ns2:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010_SP1"></ns2:RequestServerVersion></SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:FindItem xsi:type="ns1:FindItemType" Traversal="Shallow">
<ns1:ItemShape><ns2:BaseShape>IdOnly</ns2:BaseShape></ns1:ItemShape>
<ns1:IndexedPageItemView MaxEntriesReturned="50" Offset="0" BasePoint="Beginning" xsi:type="ns2:IndexedPageViewType"></ns1:IndexedPageItemView>
<ns1:ParentFolderIds><ns2:DistinguishedFolderId Id="inbox"  xsi:type="ns2:DistinguishedFolderIdType"></ns2:DistinguishedFolderId></ns1:ParentFolderIds></ns1:FindItem>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Do we miss something needed? or we made the incorrect SOAP request?
Our development environment is Mac OS 10.8, xcode 4.5, C++, gSOAP 2.8, and Exchange Server 2010. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine except the spaces in the namespace defined for the **xsi** prefix.